# Is there any way to create looping with Tag Helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Is there any way to create a Tag Helper that somehow iterates (repeater like) over the inner tag helpers?  That is, something like:

```
<big-ul iterateover='x'>
  <little-li value='uses x somehow'></little-li>
</bg-ul>
```

I know I can do it with razor foreach but trying to figure out how to do it without having to switch to c# code in my html.

Comment: I did find some notes in this post under taghelpers https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, by using the `TagHelperContext.Items` property. From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.taghelpercontext):

> Gets the collection of items used to communicate with other `ITagHelpers`. This `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is copy-on-write in order to ensure items added to this collection are visible only to other `ITagHelpers` targeting child elements.

What this means is that you can pass objects from the parent tag helper to its children.

For example, let's assume you want to iterate over a list of `Employee` :

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In your view, you'll use (for example):

```cs
@{ 
    var mylist = new[]
    {
        new Employee { Name = "Alexander", LastName = "Grams" },
        new Employee { Name = "Sarah", LastName = "Connor" }
    };
}
<big-ul iterateover="@mylist">
    <little-li></little-li>
</big-ul>
```

and the two tag helpers:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("big-ul", Attributes = IterateOverAttr)]
public class BigULTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string IterateOverAttr = "iterateover";

    [HtmlAttributeName(IterateOverAttr)]
    public IEnumerable<object> IterateOver { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "ul";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

        foreach(var item in IterateOver)
        {
            // this is the key line: we pass the list item to the child tag helper
            context.Items["item"] = item;
            output.Content.AppendHtml(await output.GetChildContentAsync(false));
        }
    }
}

[HtmlTargetElement("little-li")]
public class LittleLiTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // retrieve the item from the parent tag helper
        var item = context.Items["item"] as Employee;

        output.TagName = "li";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

        output.Content.AppendHtml($"<span>{item.Name}</span><span>{item.LastName}</span>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we make `LittleLiTagHelper` generic so that it can accept any type? the inner html should be dynamic too. For example a generic `<table>` tag with a `<tr>` child that can iterate over an `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: It can't be generic because the tag names are strings, not types. However you can certainly create an abstract base class with abstract properties that contain the wanted tag names.

Comment: `as Employee`? How can you be sure it's an Employee? A more general approach would be better so that those taghelpers can be used for any collection.

Comment: @Bamdad you can remove the `as Employee`, in which case `item` would be of type `object `. You can then use a switch statement with pattern matching to generate html based on the item's type.

Comment: @Métoule That again is not out of box enough. For every type you need to use in the helpers, you should add it to the switch statement. (If you remember to, after three months.) There should be a generic trick to achieve this goal and there is none at the moment.