# ASP.NET Core MVC tag helper for collections data binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using a model that contains a List of "Country" and i'm using...

```
            <input asp-for="Countries" type="hidden" />
```

... to do my data binding but when it renders it populates the value attribute with the toString() of the list. so its just...

```
<input type="hidden" id="Countries" name="Countries" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Country]">
```

is there a proper way of doing data binding for a model that contains a collections using tag helpers in in asp.net core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to create looping with ASP.NET MVC6 Core tag helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132564/any-way-to-create-looping-with-asp-net-mvc6-core-tag-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following technique:

```
@{
    for (int i=0; i<Model.Countries.Count(); i++) {
        <input asp-for="Model.Countries[i].Name" type="text"/>
    } 
}
```

That should do the trick.